# Load local chrome user profile to Heroku to use it with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

I want to build a simple web scraper using python selenium and deploy it on Heroku. I've already done the deployment process with chromedriver and chrome buildpacks and everything is working fine. But I still need to implement one thing. I want to use my local chrome profile so that I don't have to sign up into Google. This is working fine locally by using

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

To access my chrome profile on Heroku I just uploaded it the whole folder in the same directory as the code. After the deployment I can access the folder under /app/User Data and can see all files. However if I pass

```
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=/app/User Data")
```

to the Driver, it doesn't load the profile and the login process fails. I tried to get more information by printing the source code of "chrome://version", but that's just an empty page.

Do you have any suggestion what I can try instead to get it working? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to login you can use  https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/ to login. It is selenium but it doesn't get detected when signing in.